# About the number of solutions of $a\log(x)=x^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was wondering if you could help me with that problem:

Find the solutions of\begin{equation} a·\log(x)=x^2, \end{equation} according to the values of $a\gt 0$.

I thought that I could write \begin{equation} f(x)=a·\log(x)-x^2, \end{equation} and do the derivative \begin{equation} f'(x)=\frac{a}{x}-2x, \end{equation} and maybe find where is decreasing or increasing, but I don't know if I'm doing it right, and I don't know how to continue. I would appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $\log x = u$, so that $$a u = e^{2u}.$$ Now you have a fixed exponential function and a family of lines with variable angular coefficient, and you can easily find out how many intersections occur as $a$ varies.

Comment: Hi Siminore. I'm still trying to find out how to formalise your answer. Could you explain it a little more? Thanks a lot.

Comment: There are different ways. For example, you could draw the graph of the exponential and then the straight lines. Or you could draw the graph $y=\frac{e^{2u}}{u}$.

Comment: The derivative of $y$ gives me that $y'=0$ at $\frac{1}{2}$. I know it's the solution, but why?

Answer (score 1):

A few quick sketches should tell you that when there is exactly one solution, $f(x)=f'(x)=0$, i.e.
$$\frac{a}{x}=2x \implies a=2x^{2} \implies 2x^{2}\log{x}=x^{2} \implies x^{2}(2\log x-1)=0$$
So we either have $x=0$ and $a=0$ (trivial case) or $x=e^{1/2}$ and $a=2e$. For any smaller positive value of $a$ there are no solutions, and for any larger value there are two solutions. Again by inspection, for negative $a$ there is always one root $0<x<1$

**This is not rigorous at all, but is a nice way of thinking about it**

Comment: I'm sorry if I am asking an obvious thing, but why can you say that when there's exactly one solution, $f(x)=f'(x)=0$?

Comment: This was the non-rigorous part. Picture a set of axes in your head, with $y=a\log x$ and $y=x^{2}$ sketched on them, with $a\log x$ underneath. Imagine 'stretching' the $\log$ curve up towards $y=x^{2}$ (this corresponds to increasing $a$). When there is exactly one root, the curves are *only just* touching, so they are both intersecting ($f(x)=0$) *and tangent* ($f'(x)=0$).

Comment: Thank you, now I understood it perfectly, do you have any idea of how I could write this to be rigorous?

Comment: I think such a method does exist, but I'm afraid I'm not sure how I'd write it exactly (analysis isn't my strong point!). Siminore's answer, on the other hand, is much simpler and easier to make rigorous, I would say.