# Solving $ax-b\cdot\log_2(x)=0$

Tags: calculus

How can I solve

$$ax-b\cdot\log_2(x)=0$$

Of course, I can transform to

$$ax=b\cdot\log_2(x)$$
$$2^{ax}=x^b$$

But this isn't any better, because I also don't know, how to handle this one.

I found this question [About the number of solutions of $a\log(x)=x^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/688524/120537), which would fit, if it had a solution I can understand and adapt.

---

As a clarification, the original question is from an introduction to algorithms. It is about the comparison of two algorithms, running in $8n^2$ and $64n\log(n)$ steps. I started with

$$8n^2=64n\log(n)$$

and made the first obvious transformation

$$n=8\log(n)$$

But that's all, what is left from school, 30 years ago. I then [plotted](http://graphsketch.com/?eqn1_eqn=x&eqn2_eqn=8*log%28x%29) the two functions, to see if there's a solution. But that is all, I could come up with.
[image: n vs 8*log(n)]

Comment: Can you say something about a,b to restrict the possible cases?

Comment: numerically. No closed form solution

Comment: @Stefanos Please see the updated question, a=1, b=8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** This can be solved in terms of the [Lambert *W* function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: Thank you for this hint, that's a lot to digest :-)

Comment: @OlafDietsche not really. It's just a special function somebody defined to give the solution of $y=xe^x$ a fancy name. At the end of the day it just means you have a transcendental equation that has no solution within the "conventional" set of functions. Most of transcendental equations are like that - throw together some different functions and you'll have to solve it numerically.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation.

Answer (score 1):

For $a=1$ and $b=8$ the solutions of the equation, are the roots of the function $$f(x)=2^x-x^8$$ A graph of the function with the roots is posted below 
[image]

As can be seen in the table on the left, the roots of this function are $$r_1=-0.92 \qquad \text{ and } \qquad r_2=1.1$$

Comment: Thank you for your effort.

Comment: You are welcome!